# JavaScript Injection - Manipulate Objects

Tags: javascript, injection

I want to inject JavaScript to a website **locally** via address bar.
The purpose is to make some modifications of the website **only for me**.

What is the correct way to find and then **manipulate objects / variables**? Especially when the JS is obfuscated.

Say, I know for sure there has to be an instance of a certain class which has a certain method.
F12 both on Chrome and on FF did not help me too much but maybe I am doing something wrong.

To be more precise, I will give a real problem.
[This website](http://lichess.org/) is an open source chess server.
It uses an open source library to represent a board ([github](https://github.com/ornicar/chessground)).
I know for sure that there has to be a `move()` method.

Now the question is simple: how do I find this instance and calling `move()` in order to programmatically move pieces?

Comment: you might not be able to; it's possible to execute JS in a pure local context, ex inside an IIFE or module, with DOM subscriptions inside the wrapper. you would be better off using tampermonkey that the URL bar, which would be a total PITA to debug/dev

Comment: @dandavis, and what if I make changes to the browser settings? On what level I might not be able to? On browser level or it is a limitation of the interpreter?

Comment: I fail to see how this is a question about information **security**, i.e. I consider it off-topic.

Comment: its a limit of the language. you would have to hack V8. that said, you can simulate human interaction, so that you can "click" on the board and the program will behave as expected. not as cool as getting into the code, but universally possible.